# Python tkinter (copy/paste not working with other languages)

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, keyboard-events

I found out that whenever i switch the language from english to russian tkinter stops reacting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

It still works when i switch back to english, even if the text is in russian.

I tried all code snippets i could find on stack exchange remotely related to copy-paste topic, adding stuff similar to original code like `self.bind('<Control-м>', self.paste)` ("м" is the same button in russian as "v" in english), but still nothing works.

Would really appreciate any help/ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: hi mere. related to shortcut keys inside python apps, i've used a library named: pyHook. (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook). please give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry   

def _onKeyRelease(event):
    ctrl  = (event.state & 0x4) != 0
    if event.keycode==88 and  ctrl and event.keysym.lower() != "x": 
        event.widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>")

    if event.keycode==86 and  ctrl and event.keysym.lower() != "v": 
        event.widget.event_generate("<<Paste>>")

    if event.keycode==67 and  ctrl and event.keysym.lower() != "c":
        event.widget.event_generate("<<Copy>>")


master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500+1+1")
master.bind_all("<Key>", _onKeyRelease, "+")
Entry(master).pack()
Entry(master).pack()
Entry(master).pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

I did this.

1.First received the current layout language on the advice of [here](http://python.su/forum/topic/1946/):

```
def is_ru_lang_keyboard(self):
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    return hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419'
```

2. Then I defined the keys() method taking into account the layout, because without a condition in the case of the English layout, the method gave a duplicate string when inserting:

```
    def keys(event):
        if self.is_ru_lang_keyboard():
            if event.keycode==86:
                event.widget.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
            if event.keycode==67: 
                event.widget.event_generate("<<Copy>>")    
            if event.keycode==88: 
                event.widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>")    
            if event.keycode==65535: 
                event.widget.event_generate("<<Clear>>")
            if event.keycode==65: 
                event.widget.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>")
```

3.Bound the keys() method of the Entry field to the "Control-KeyPress" event:

```
self.my_entry.bind("<Control-KeyPress>", keys)
```

Comment: To use this, you'd have to import ctypes module. Keep in mind that ctypes.windll will only work on windows OS so this solution is not applicable for Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<Key>` to check what `keycode` is used when you press `Control-м` and then use it to find `keysym` on page like [Tcl/Tk - keysym](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm). Maybe you will have to use `<Control-Cyrillic_em>`

```
import tkinter as tk

def copy(event):
    print('copy')

def paste(event):
    print('paste')

def test(event):    
    print('event.char:', event.char)
    print('event.keycode:', event.keycode)
    print('event.keysym:', event.keysym)
    print('---')

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<Key>', test)

root.bind('<Control-c>', copy)
root.bind('<Control-v>', paste)
root.bind('<Control-Cyrillic_em>', paste)

root.mainloop()
```