# Ctrl+C/V doesn't work in tkinter GUI python 3 when you keyboard isn't in English

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've created a tkinter desktop app where I have labels, inputs, buttons, etc.
I need to copy and paste text into tk.Entry, but when I have non-english keyboard (for example, my native Ukrainian language is on), simple commands like ctrl+A/C/V doesn't work in GUI.

I couldn't find a solution on the web that's why I decided to ask the question here. How do I make the tkinter GUI execute commands in any keyboard layout?

Comment: Try and see if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496024/13629335